# Вызов функции при выборе элемента в select

Tags: php, javascript

Есть форма с select

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<select name="pay_method">
   <option value="price_nal">Наличные</option>
   <option value="price_beznal">Безналичные</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="calc" id="calc">Пересчитать...</button>
</form>
```

При выборе любого элемента и нажатии кнопки "Пересчитать" происходит следующее:

```
if(isset($_POST['pay_method']) and $_POST['pay_method'] != '')
{
     //Удаляем текующую сессию с информацией о способе оплаты
     $this->session->delete('price');

     $this->session->set('price', $_POST['pay_method']);
}
//Перерасчет суммы и стоимостей товаров
$this->_calc($_POST);
```

Помогите реализовать следующее: что бы при выборе "Наличные" или "Безналичные" происходило тоже, что и при нажатии кнопки "Пересчитать"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<select onchange="document.form[0].submit()">
...
</select>
```

Comment: что то никаких изменений не происходит

Comment: попробуйте задать индентификатор форме и выбрать форму по нему: 

    <select onchange="GetElementByID("myform").submit()">

Comment: Кавычки для myform" насколько я понимаю - одинарные. И все равно нет результата(

Comment: Да, кавычки такие. 

Почитайте здесь: http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/5882-gehg-select-i-sobytie-onselect.html

Comment: Может дело в кнопке? Тут вместо input type="submit" написано button type="submit"

Comment: кстати

    document.getElementByID();

попробуйте так. Браузер на ошибки ссылается?

Comment: Попробуйте в <option> создать событие onClick и туда запихать нужное выражение

Answer (score 3):

Помогло

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery, Luke. [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/)